# Rspec DRY: apply example to all contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, dry

is it possible to shorten this Rspec?
I'd like to extract the line `it { expect { author.destroy }.to_not raise_error }` not to repeat it in every context. Shared examples are some way, but finally, it generates more code than below redundant version.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Author, type: :model do
  describe 'destroying' do
    context 'when no books assigned' do
      subject!(:author) { FactoryBot.create :author_with_no_books }

      it { expect { author.destroy }.to_not raise_error }
      # other examples
    end

    context 'when there are some books' do
      subject!(:author) { FactoryBot.create :author_with_books }

      it { expect { author.destroy }.to_not raise_error }
      # other examples
    end

    context 'when there are some posts' do
      subject!(:author) { FactoryBot.create :author_with_posts }

      it { expect { author.destroy }.to_not raise_error }
      # other examples
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you had more of these, then shared examples would be more beneficial. But as it is now, it's not too bad. Short and descriptive, I'd leave this as-is.

Comment: Don't use `it {}` as the failure message will be very cryptic. Describe the behaviour you are testing. `it "can be deleted", { expect { author.destroy }.to_not raise_error }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shared_examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) with a parameter instead of [abusing `subject`](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/):

```
RSpec.describe Author, type: :model do
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods # you can move this to rails_helper.rb

  RSpec.shared_examples "can be destroyed" do |thing|
    it "can be destroyed" do
      expect { thing.destroy }.to_not raise_error
    end
  end

  describe 'destroying' do
    context 'without books' do
      include_examples "can be destroyed", create(:author_with_no_books)
    end

    context 'with books' do
      include_examples "can be destroyed", create(:author_with_books)
    end

    context 'with posts' do
      include_examples "can be destroyed", create(:author_with_posts)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this answer! Thanks! ;)